# Different Classes of NP

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, decision-problem

I was solving problems related to P and NP where I encountered the following problem:

Given a standard definition of NP,

 if x belongs to L then there exists y such that |y| <= |x|^d and A(x, y) = 1;

if x does not belong to L then for every y with |y| <= |x|^d we have A(x, y) = 0.


1. what is the new class formed when we don't include the second statement?

2. what is the new class formed when we don't include the first statement?

I am well versed with the definitions of P and NP but unable to figure out how to determine these new classes.

 Any help in understanding these concepts would be appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3916655/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/132367/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a big hint to help you solve the problem:

> Can you give an example of a language that *is* in this class?  Can you give an example of a language that is *not* in this class?

Comment: I am referring to standard 3SAT problem as a reference example to solve this problem. I am unable to figure out that how any input instance will not satisfy the circuits. I came to a conclusion that the algorithm will forcefully satisfy any input x in the circuit.